# Unknown "feature" function

Tags: matlab

I'm totally new to MATLAB, and I have dificulties with some code I have to understand for my project.

Here is the code :

```
feature         = feature(1:64,:,:);
feature(43,:,:) = [];
feature(33,:,:) = [];
feature         = feature([36,38,45,46,47,53,54,55,59,60,61],:,:);
```

I don't realy understand what does the `feature` function does or is. Is it a table? A matrix? And what does `(1:64,:,:)` mean? The same for `(43,:,:)`? Is it a MATLAB notation ? Where can I find a sum up of these notations?

Comment: In your case, `feature` is just a matrix (an array) with 3 dimensions. I would recommend to read this article : [matrix indexing in matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `feature` is a multidimensional matrix of dimension 3 (aka 3D array, e.g. RGB image). In fact, almost everything in Matlab is a matrix.

> And what does (1:64,:,:) mean?

This says take elements from 1:64 along the first dimension of the variable. `1:64` expands to `[1, 2, 3, ..., 64]`

feature now has size `64xNxK`

> The same for (43,:,:) ?

This says give me the elements at row 43

When you say

```
feature(43,:,:) = []
```

you delete this row from the matrix. Now the matrix size is one row less.

See here for the documentations http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html